# Scrapy cralwed 0 pages, scraped 0 item. What things should I check for the troubleshooting?

Tags: python, parsing, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm trying to parse the post of this website to collect the texts for sentiment analysis. Here is the code that I'm working with.

```
# ~/dcscraper/dcscraper/spiders/spider.py

import scrapy
import pandas as pd

class dcscraper(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "dcscraper"

    def start_requests(self):
        start_urls = ["https://gall.dcinside.com/board/lists?id=bitcoins_new1&page=1"]
        for url in start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)
    
    def parse(self, response):
        # parse the links of the posts, join the links with 'https://gall.dcinside.com/', and yield the result which will be called by the text_parse function
        for link in response.xpath('//*[@id="container"]/section/article/div/table/tbody/tr/td/a[contains(@href, "/board/view")'):
            yield scrapy.Request(url=response.urljoin(link), callback=self.text_parse)
        # convert the last element of url of the response which is splitted by 'page=' into integer, and add 1 to it, and convert it to string again, and then combine the splitted urls[0] with string 'page=', and name the string next_page
        next_page = response.url.split('page=')[0] + 'page=' + str(int(response.url.split('page=')[1]) + 1)
        # if the next_page is not the same as the response url, and if the request reponse of next_page is 200, yield the next_page which will be called by the parse function, or stop the spider
        if next_page != response.url and scrapy.Request(url=next_page).status == 200:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=next_page, callback=self.parse)
    
    # define a function text_parse
    def text_parse(self, response):
        for text in response.xpath('//*[@id="container"]/section/article/div[contains(@class, "view_content_wrap")]'):
            # find an element of the post of the title and call this title
            title = text.xpath('span[contains(@class, "title_subject")]')
            # find an elements of the body of the post, join them with ' ', and name this body_text
            body_text = ' '.join(text.xpath('div[contains(@class, "write_div")]/br').extract())
            # find an element of date posted, and name this post_date
            post_date = text.xpath('span[contains(@class, "gall_date")]')
            # make pandas dataframe with title, body_text, post_date and append this dataframe to a csv file in the file path '/home/luxiant/dcscraper/result/result.csv', or save this dataframe as a csv file to path '/home/luxiant/dcscraper/result/result.csv' if the file does not exist
            pd.DataFrame({'title':title , 'body_text':body_text, 'post_date':post_date}).to_csv('/home/luxiant/dcscraper/result/result.csv', mode='a', header=False, index=False)
```

```
# ~/dcscraper/dcscraper/settings.py

BOT_NAME = 'dcscraper'
SPIDER_MODULES = ['dcscraper.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'dcscraper.spiders'
USER_AGENT = 'Googlebot/2.1 (+http://www.google.com/bot.html)'
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = True
REQUEST_FINGERPRINTER_IMPLEMENTATION = '2.7'
TWISTED_REACTOR = 'twisted.internet.asyncioreactor.AsyncioSelectorReactor'
```

and in terminal,

```
cd dcscraper
scrapy crawl dcscraper -o ~/dcscraper/result/result.csv
```

and here is the log.

```
2022-11-22 15:57:53 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.7.0 started (bot: dcscraper)
2022-11-22 15:57:53 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.9.1.0, libxml2 2.10.3, cssselect 1.2.0, parsel 1.7.0, w3lib 2.0.1, Twisted 22.10.0, Python 3.10.8 (main, Nov  1 2022, 14:18:21) [GCC 12.2.0], pyOpenSSL 22.1.0 (OpenSSL 3.0.7 1 Nov 2022), cryptography 38.0.3, Platform Linux-5.15.78-1-MANJARO-x86_64-with-glibc2.36
2022-11-22 15:57:53 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
{'BOT_NAME': 'dcscraper',
 'EDITOR': '/usr/bin/nano',
 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'dcscraper.spiders',
 'REQUEST_FINGERPRINTER_IMPLEMENTATION': '2.7',
 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True,
 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['dcscraper.spiders'],
 'TWISTED_REACTOR': 'twisted.internet.asyncioreactor.AsyncioSelectorReactor',
 'USER_AGENT': 'Googlebot/2.1 (+http://www.google.com/bot.html)'}
2022-11-22 15:57:53 [asyncio] DEBUG: Using selector: EpollSelector
2022-11-22 15:57:53 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor: twisted.internet.asyncioreactor.AsyncioSelectorReactor
2022-11-22 15:57:53 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using asyncio event loop: asyncio.unix_events._UnixSelectorEventLoop
2022-11-22 15:57:53 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: 0ceb3c2ae12e2e05
2022-11-22 15:57:53 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage',
 'scrapy.extensions.feedexport.FeedExporter',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2022-11-22 15:57:53 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2022-11-22 15:57:53 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2022-11-22 15:57:53 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2022-11-22 15:57:53 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2022-11-22 15:57:53 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2022-11-22 15:57:53 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2022-11-22 15:57:53 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://gall.dcinside.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2022-11-22 15:57:53 [filelock] DEBUG: Attempting to acquire lock 140598032389680 on /home/luxiant/.cache/python-tldextract/3.10.8.final__usr__7d8fdf__tldextract-3.4.0/publicsuffix.org-tlds/de84b5ca2167d4c83e38fb162f2e8738.tldextract.json.lock
2022-11-22 15:57:53 [filelock] DEBUG: Lock 140598032389680 acquired on /home/luxiant/.cache/python-tldextract/3.10.8.final__usr__7d8fdf__tldextract-3.4.0/publicsuffix.org-tlds/de84b5ca2167d4c83e38fb162f2e8738.tldextract.json.lock
2022-11-22 15:57:53 [filelock] DEBUG: Attempting to release lock 140598032389680 on /home/luxiant/.cache/python-tldextract/3.10.8.final__usr__7d8fdf__tldextract-3.4.0/publicsuffix.org-tlds/de84b5ca2167d4c83e38fb162f2e8738.tldextract.json.lock
2022-11-22 15:57:53 [filelock] DEBUG: Lock 140598032389680 released on /home/luxiant/.cache/python-tldextract/3.10.8.final__usr__7d8fdf__tldextract-3.4.0/publicsuffix.org-tlds/de84b5ca2167d4c83e38fb162f2e8738.tldextract.json.lock
2022-11-22 15:57:53 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://gall.dcinside.com/board/lists?id=bitcoins_new1&page=1> (referer: None)
2022-11-22 15:57:53 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET https://gall.dcinside.com/board/lists?id=bitcoins_new1&page=1> (referer: None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/parsel/selector.py", line 423, in xpath
    result = xpathev(
  File "src/lxml/etree.pyx", line 1599, in lxml.etree._Element.xpath
  File "src/lxml/xpath.pxi", line 305, in lxml.etree.XPathElementEvaluator.__call__
  File "src/lxml/xpath.pxi", line 225, in lxml.etree._XPathEvaluatorBase._handle_result
lxml.etree.XPathEvalError: Invalid predicate

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scrapy/utils/defer.py", line 240, in iter_errback
    yield next(it)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scrapy/utils/python.py", line 338, in __next__
    return next(self.data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scrapy/utils/python.py", line 338, in __next__
    return next(self.data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scrapy/core/spidermw.py", line 79, in process_sync
    for r in iterable:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/offsite.py", line 29, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if self._filter(r, spider))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scrapy/core/spidermw.py", line 79, in process_sync
    for r in iterable:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/referer.py", line 336, in <genexpr>
    return (self._set_referer(r, response) for r in result or ())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scrapy/core/spidermw.py", line 79, in process_sync
    for r in iterable:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/urllength.py", line 28, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if self._filter(r, spider))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scrapy/core/spidermw.py", line 79, in process_sync
    for r in iterable:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/depth.py", line 32, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if self._filter(r, response, spider))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scrapy/core/spidermw.py", line 79, in process_sync
    for r in iterable:
  File "/home/luxiant/dcscraper/dcscraper/spiders/spider.py", line 14, in parse
    for link in response.xpath('//*[@id="container"]/section/article/div/table/tbody/tr/td/a[contains(@href, "/board/view")'):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scrapy/http/response/text.py", line 138, in xpath
    return self.selector.xpath(query, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/parsel/selector.py", line 430, in xpath
    raise ValueError(f"XPath error: {exc} in {query}")
ValueError: XPath error: Invalid predicate in //*[@id="container"]/section/article/div/table/tbody/tr/td/a[contains(@href, "/board/view")
2022-11-22 15:57:53 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2022-11-22 15:57:53 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 505,
 'downloader/request_count': 2,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 33699,
 'downloader/response_count': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 0.36847,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2022, 11, 22, 6, 57, 53, 838005),
 'httpcompression/response_bytes': 169467,
 'httpcompression/response_count': 2,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 9,
 'log_count/ERROR': 1,
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'memusage/max': 117219328,
 'memusage/startup': 117219328,
 'response_received_count': 2,
 'robotstxt/request_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'spider_exceptions/ValueError': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2022, 11, 22, 6, 57, 53, 469535)}
2022-11-22 15:57:53 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

What things should I check for the troubleshooting?

I first thought that it was a matter of the element that I put, so I put the xpath of the element that I want to collect, resulting in the code that I'm just showing right now.
Checking the debug log, I found that the parser does not read the adequate element. (referer: None) I think that might be one of the cause, but yet tried to deal with this.

Answer (score 0):

It tells you what the problem is in the logs.

> File "/home/luxiant/dcscraper/dcscraper/spiders/spider.py", line 14, in parse for link in response.xpath('//*[@id="container"]/section/article/div/table/tbody/tr/td/a[contains(@href, "/board/view")'):
> File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scrapy/http/response/text.py", line 138, in xpath
> return self.selector.xpath(query, **kwargs)
> ...
> raise ValueError(f"XPath error: {exc} in {query}")
> ValueError: XPath error: Invalid predicate in //*[@id="container"]/section/article/div/table/tbody/tr/td/a[contains(@href, "/board/view")
> 2022-11-22 15:57:53 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)

Which means you are not using correct syntax for your xpath selector on line 14 of your parse method.

the issue is that you never close the last set of `[]` square brackets in your expression.  It should look like this:

```
for link in response.xpath('//*[@id="container"]/section/article/div/table/tbody/tr/td/a[contains(@href, "/board/view")]'):
            yield scrapy.Request(url=response.urljoin(link), callback=self.text_parse)
```